# Angular 2 auto-rooting to homepage on App-start

Tags: routes, angular, bootstrapping, angular2-routing

I am currently developing an App with Anuglar 2 and am trying to have it route to my homepage when the app is started.

I have a main.html and a main.ts file that are loaded on their own and have various nested views (if that is the right name for those) that can be loaded in, home is one of them.

The code at this point looks something like this:

```
import {[...], Router} from 'angular2/router';

[...]

@Component({ 
  selector: 'main', 
  bindings: [Router] 
})
@View({
  directives: [[...] Router],
  templateUrl: '[...]/main.html'
})

export class mainApp {

 private router;

 constructor(router: Router)
  {
     router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }         
}

bootstrap(mainApp, [[...}, Router]);
```

[...] indicates some other code that should not matter for the issue itself.

Now with the code present, starting the App tosses the following error:

Cannot resolve all parameters for function Router(registry, parent, hostComponent) {(?, ?, ?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

How can I fix it and get the routing/auto-navigation to work?

Late edit:
Had some talks with teammates in the project about updating to angular 2 alpha 45... turns out that was actually the reason behind the issue. whole thing is working fine now with what I had to begin with (and some adjustments to what is imported).

Comment: In your `bindings` property you should pass `ROUTER_BINDINGS` (which by now is `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]`, so I'm guessing you're not using the last alpha verison). In your `directives` property you should pass `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` and you are passing it twice in `directives` and `bootstrap`, choose one of them.

Comment: `ROUTER_BINDINGS` is currently in bootstrap, I removed "Router" from the bootstrap, though that doesn't solve the error. As for the version, I am using alpha 44.

Comment: Here you have a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mbY8ng?p=preview). Things I noted : You missed `RouteConfig`, I assume in your template you have `router-outlet` but I see no `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, so probably you missed those few things. I hope it helps.

Comment: I will try the `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`. also, yes I have a router-outlet in it. `RouteConfig` is also resent, I left it out of the code though since it shouldn't be the issue. At this point, I have a menu for navigating different pages, which works entirely fine if I leave the `router.navigateByUrl('/home);` out. so my `RouteConfig` should be fine.

Comment: I tried using your example to adjust my code (mostly by adding in all parts I was missing). Now I am getting this error: `No Directive annotation found on function Router(registry, parent, hostComponent) `

Comment: Set up a plnkr to reproduce your error, otherwise we will be bind guessing for a long time

Comment: Alright, I will do that first thing tomorrow, for today I have to stop though.

Comment: I tried recreating the error by recreating a basic version of my current state of the App here: [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/sbNLyNXdx53goCns9RPm?p=preview though, it did not toss me any errors on Plunker itself (first time using Plunker)

Comment: Just create a repo, your plnkr it's not working at all (you didn't include angular, nor the config, etc). Create a repo with your current non-working project.

Comment: Well, problem is that I'm not allowed to share the project itself, otherwise I already would have.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically redirect you can use `redirectTo` like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' }
    { path: '/home', component: Home, as: 'Home' }
])
```

Check out this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/j45sVHrLPNSEHFss0HUE?p=preview

Comment: `redirctTo` didn't do the job for some reason, at least not in angular 2 alpha 44 I used before. I updated to alpha 45 now and used `router.navigateByUrl('/home');` which works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useAsDefault: true` to set your default routing, like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home', component: Home, as: 'Home', useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/other', component: Other, as: 'Other }
])
```

On startup, assuming a requested path of '/' the app will launch your home component.

Answer (score 0):

Create separeta routing module file(e.g. app-routing.module.ts) with next code:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```